# Title tags show twice

Tags: title, wp-title

My Title tags same sentence show twice. [please see it](http://www.desyfun.tk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2012-10-24_210647.jpg). how i can solve this problem . [my site](http://dewdropzone.com/)

Comment: anyone can tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the header.php file in your template folder and make sure that between the title tags, there's only this code:

```
<?php wp_title('');?>
```

That should do the trick. This error is a combination of your template files with standard settings of the Yoast SEO plugin.

Comment: where i include this code.. above i give my header.php code into my question.

Comment: here not show my full code please see from here http://www.desyfun.tk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Header-php.txt

Comment: Read my post again: you should make sure that's the only code between the title tags. This means, find the <title> tags, put the code in it and that's it. :)

Answer (score 2):

This can happen due to Yoast SEO plugin inserting it's own title. GO to `http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_titles#top#home`

[image]

Comment: then what i can do?

Comment: remove the "title template" string. This should reset it to whatever your template is serving

Comment: if i remove all title template then any effect of my seo?

Comment: Not all, just the one for the Homepage.

Comment: just the one in the screenshot I added

Comment: i remove it's all code but it's not working see it.... http://www.desyfun.tk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2012-10-24_221410.jpg